# Looking for an open-source, Java-based Personalization engine

Tags: java, open-source, personalization

Maybe my google-fu is broken this morning, but I can't find anything that meets the general requirements of:

- rules based (like jbpm/drools)
- content/targeting centric (like the old ATG Personalization Server)
- open source
- java

Anyone have any pointers? Leads?

Thanks!

Comment: It's stupid that this is offtopic and closed. Good question.

Answer (score 0):

May be not exact what you are looking for but you can find a personalization engine in the two open source java cms systems

**Hippo CMS** 
http://www.onehippo.com
It´s called personas, have a look at http://vimeo.com/64808537

**Jahia CMS**
But I think the personalization is only available in a lab version of Jahia.